# Ajuda para construção de Expressão Regular

Tags: regex

Relativamente à *string* identificada abaixo, precisava obter o valor ABCD através da utilização de uma expressão regular, preciso de uma ajuda para construir essa expressão regular.

`Team(\\\'ABCD\\\')`

Comment: Qual linguagem? Quer validar ou extrair o que esta no meio de `Team(...)`?

Answer (score 4):

A expressão regular seria:

```
\bTeam\(\\+\'([\s\S]+?)\\+\'\)
```

O `([\s\S]+?)` é quem gera o grupo 1 e obtém o resultado somente de dentro do `Team(\\'...'\\)`, já o `\b` no começo é um meta-caractere que identifica se é uma palavra, ou seja se encontrar algo como `TestTeam()` vai ignorar, somente separadas por espaços ou strings que comecem com `Team()` irão "casar" com a regex

Se for JavaScript:

```js
var str = "Team(\\'ABCD\\')";
var resultados = /\bTeam\(\\+\'([\s\S]+?)\\+\'\)/g.exec(str);

console.log(resultados[1]);

var str = "Team(\\'foo bar baz\\')";
var resultados = /\bTeam\(\\+\'([\s\S]+?)\\+\'\)/g.exec(str);

console.log(resultados[1]);
```

Se for PHP:

```
$str = "Team(\\'ABCD\\')";

if (preg_match("#\bTeam\(\\\\+\'([\s\S]+?)\\\\+\'\)#", $str, $resultados)) {
    var_dump($resultados[1]);
}
```

Se for Python:

```
import re

str = "Team(\\'ABCD\\')"
parttern = r'\bTeam\(\\+\'([\s\S]+?)\\+\'\)'

p = re.compile(parttern)
resultado = p.search(str).group(1)

print(resultado)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, utilizei a primeira opção e funcionou!

Comment: @Márcio poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Se ainda não souber como fazer leia este *faq* https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635 - Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar esta expressão:

```
[A-Z]+\b
```

Irá pegar a sequência de letras maiúsculas (`[A-Z]`) da direita para a esquerda (`+\b`) até que não encontre mais uma letra maiúscula, ou seja, em `Team(\\'ABCD\\')`, irá retornar `ABCD`.

**Veja em JavaScript:**

```js
var string = "Team(\\'ABCD\\')";
var result = /[A-Z]+\b/.exec(string);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Como retorna apenas 1 resultado, você usa o índice `[0]` em `result[0]`.